# phpMyAdmin updated from 4.6.6 to 4.7.5 generates "Undefined index: ssl_key"

Tags: phpmyadmin

I recently tried to update my phpMyAdmin instance from version `4.6.6` to `4.7.5`.  The update itself went fine however I'm seeing these warning messages at the bottom of most of the pages now after I connect to a database:

```
Undefined index: ssl_key
Undefined index: ssl_cert
Undefined index: ssl_ca_path
Undefined index: ssl_ciphers
```

The database I'm connecting to uses a self-signed certificate.  In my phpMyAdmin configuration I have these SSL-related directives:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ca'] = '../ssl/cacert.crt';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlssl'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlssl_ca'] = '../ssl/cacert.crt';
```

Under `4.6.6` this was sufficient.  Even under `4.7.5` this seems to work with regards to using a SSL connection however it displays these warning messages.

[Warning messages displayed within phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkL20.jpg)

I've tried adding these other SSL directives:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_verify'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlssl_verify'] = false;
```

and the warning messages still persist.

How can I determine what is causing these warning messages?

Comment: To be clear, the ssl directives you've pasted here from your configuration are in `config.inc.php`, not `libraries/config.default.php`, right?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, and I'm not able to reproduce it. Have you modified `libraries/config.default.php` at all? Those lines that are reported missing now (such as `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_key'] = null;` are defined in the defaults file (which is never meant to be edited) and the most logical reason for this error message is if someone's removed those lines from there. Can you open `libraries/config.default.php` in a text editor and search for the values 'ssl_key' and 'ssl_ca' to see if either of those are present in the defaults file?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch The SSL directives I mentioned in my post were only made to the `config.inc.php` file.  I just did a fresh update by doing these steps:

* I downloaded a fresh copy of `phpMyAdmin-4.7.5-all-languages.zip` and extracted it to my web server.

* I downloaded a fresh copy of the Metro theme, extracted it and put it in the `themes` directory.

* I took the `config.inc.php` from my working phpMyAdmin 4.6.6 copy and put it into the root of the phpMyAdmin directory.

I opened phpMyAdmin and signed into one of the databases and got those same warning messages.

Comment: Could you tell me which PHP version you're using?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch  I think I've found what's causing the issue.  Stack Overflow's comments aren't long enough for me to post the details.  Is there a better place where I can post the details?  I suspect it's a bug in `phpMyAdmin` relating to code changes from the 4.6.x branch to the 4.7.x branch.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to be through. If it's a bug, it's most helpful to post it to https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/new as well. You should be able to post an answer to this thread which allows you much more space than the comment box does.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch Now I'm not sure if I actually found a bug or just a bad configuration on my part.  When preparing my Github bug, I noticed in the phpMyAdmin documentation that it says to use `control_*` to specify directives for the control user.  I was using `controluser`, `controlpass`, `controlssl` and `controlss_ca`.  I changed them to use the `control_` equivalents and that caused the warnings to disappear.  It looks like there was a change in directive names associated with `control_*` so I'm guessing my 4.6.x configuration file just needed to be updated.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @IsaacBennetch I spoke too quickly.  I'm not sure why those warnings disappeared but they are back again even with the changes I made to the `config.inc.php` file.  Next week I'll put my notes together and file the bug report.  Maybe someone more familiar with the code will be able to see something.  Thanks again!